# Comma breaking JQuery in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a bit of jQuery I'm using on a website that is breaking in IE due to a comma after the first function. I'm no jQuery expert, and this code is likely a bit haphazardly written. Is there a way I can rewrite this to remove the comma and get IE functionality?

```
$("#d1").hoverIntent(
      function () {
        $("#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10").hide();
        $("#num2,#num3,#num4,#num5,#num6,#num7,#num8,#num9,#num10").hide();
        $("#c1").stop(true).fadeIn("slow");
        $("#prompt").stop(true).fadeOut("slow");
        $("#numStar").stop(true).fadeOut("slow");
        $("#num1").stop(true).fadeIn("slow");
      }, 
      function () {
      }
    );
```

Comment: Nothing happens on hover

Comment: Your code is valid. Why would you want to remove the comma? That will cause the code to not run in any browser.

Comment: The comma is making the code not function in IE at all.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. Are you sure the extra comma that is breaking IE isn't elsewhere?

Comment: use hover instead of hoverIntent

Comment: hoverIntent delays the hover since there are 10 numbers that are possible to hover over. It ensures that jQuery doesn't get behind in displaying and flash through different hovers. I read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366410/simple-jquery-callbacks-break-in-ie that commas break IE, that's why I made that assumption.

Comment: Bad commas break IE, such as `["foo","bar","foobar",]` your comma is perfectly valid.

Comment: @josephndenton: Only *trailing* commas break IE.  Such as `{a: 12, b:13,}`.

Answer (score 1):

See http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html. Look at `var config = ...`.

```
$("#d1").hoverIntent({
  over:
    function () {
      $("#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10").hide();
      $("#num2,#num3,#num4,#num5,#num6,#num7,#num8,#num9,#num10").hide();
      $("#c1").stop(true).fadeIn("slow");
      $("#prompt").stop(true).fadeOut("slow");
      $("#numStar").stop(true).fadeOut("slow");
      $("#num1").stop(true).fadeIn("slow");
   },
   out: function () { }
});
```

Comment: On that same page, it shows sample code using it the same way as josephndenton is using it. This is just an alternate syntax.

Comment: Maybe an IE JavaScript issue, maybe related to an empty function. I wonder what happens if instead of `{ }` one writes `{ return 42; }`. But okay, maybe `id=d1` occurs twice or isn't an appropiate element.